# PowerShellでInvoke-Commandコマンド実行時エラーについて

Tags: powershell

Windows PowerShell でInvoke-Commandコマンドを実行したところ下記のエラーメッセージが出ました。
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { &"D:\Program Files\C.exe" 引数・・ } -ComputerName "B"

エラーメッセージ
Could not connect to ～ database: ユーザー　'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' はログインできませんでした。

実行環境等は、ローカルPCからリモートデスクトップ接続で"A"(Windows Server 2012) に接続し、
"A"サーバーのWindows PowerShellからコマンドを実行。"B"(Windows Server 2012)に存在する"C.exe"を実行すると
更に別のサーバー"D"(Windows Server 2012)のSQL ServerのDBを参照して値を返します。

"D"サーバーのDBを参照しようとして接続できないためエラーメッセージされるようです。
リモート先からさらに別のマシンのDBを参照することが上記のコマンドでは無理なのでしょうか。
解決策がありましたらお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"C.exe"でのSQL Server接続が「統合Windows認証」となっているためだと思われます。この場合Windows上の実行ユーザーが接続権限を持っている必要がありますので、 [`Invoke-Command`](https://technet.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/hh849719.aspx)の`-Credential`オプションで"D"にログインできるユーザーを指定すればよいのではないでしょうか。
例えば"B"にリモートデスクトップで接続して"C.exe"を実行した場合はエラーが出ないのであれば、そのログインユーザーを指定してみてください。

また"C.exe"の使用する接続文字列をWindowsアカウントと関係のない「SQL Server認証」に変更することでも回避できます。

Answer (score -1):

ご回答ありがとうございます。いろいろ調べた結果、ダブルホップを使用したリモートコマンドの実行(CredSSP)で解決できました。